# What should I put in the body of the response for this POST request?

Tags: php, rest, post, httpresponse, slim

I'm trying to make a REST API that uses a `POST` to create a new object in my database. I'm using the Slim framework.

The problem it's that I'm not sure about what I exactly have to put in these lines on my `POST` method:

```
$app->response->headers->set("Content-type","application/json");
$app->response->status(200);
$app->response->body(json_encode(**Here they put the name of the type of the object that they have in their database**));
```

My full `POST` route is:

```
$app->post("/cars/", function() use($app)
{
    $idCar = $app->request->post("idCar");
    $name = $app->request->post("name");

    try{
        $connection = getConnection();
        $dbh = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO cars VALUES(?,?)");
        $dbh->bindParam(1,$idCar);
        $dbh->bindParam(2,$name);

        $dbh->execute();
        $connection = null;

        $app->response->headers->set("Content-type","application/json");
        $app->response->status(200);
        $app->response->body(json_encode(**What I have to put here?**));

    }catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
});
```

In the table `cars` there are objects `Car`.

Should I put it like this?:

```
$app->response->headers->set("Content-type","application/json");
$app->response->status(200);
$app->response->body(json_encode($Car));
```

I'm a bit confused because in the tutorials that I saw before, in the `POST` method they don't have any reference to the name of the variable inside the `POST` route. For example, if they use `$fruit` they didn't declare any variable named `$fruit` inside their route.

What should I do? Is my answer correct?

Comment: `phpmyadmin` is not a database. **MYSQL** is a database that `phpMyAdmin' can be used to look at and manipulate!!!

Comment: I would suggest that you should be returning some sort of status information telling the caller that the process completed correctly or failed. However you dont check any statuses from the database access code so even you dont actually know if it was successful or not

Comment: @RiggsFolly I'm sorry, I'm really new in this field. Do you know what I put in the place that I have doubts? Thank you for correct me!

Comment: @RiggsFolly I just want to use my `POST` method from Android. Would be something different? (The tutorial that I saw it's for use `Slim framework ` with `Android`.

Comment: Did you set up your connection to generate exceptions? i.e. `$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
`

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes, I put it on my `connect.php` file

Comment: What response do you want to send back to the user after insertion?

Comment: @hjpotter92 Do you mean, for example, a text that says "Your Car has been added succesfully"?.

Comment: Exactly that. just pass it to `json_encode`

Comment: @hjpotter92 Then maybe I have a wrong idea of what it's `json_encode`. I think  you have to pass to the `json_encode` the result of the `insert` sentence. Is it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is that you can put *whatever you want* in your response.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19199872/best-practice-for-restful-post-response).

This is a design problem, not a question of being "correct".  You should ask yourself how you intend for the API to be consumed.  Once the consumer creates the object, will they need a convenient way to access it again (without having to look it up based on some other criteria)?  In that case, you might want to return just the `id` of the object you created in your response.  You could also return the entire object in your response, but be careful - in some cases, there might be something in the database representation of a `Car` that should not be available to the end user.  For example, maybe they should see the `Car`'s `name`, `make`, and `model`, but not its `buyerSocialSecurityNumber`.

In any case, you'll need to fetch any additional information after running the `INSERT` query with another query.  For example, assuming there is more information than just the `id` and `name`, I could do something like:

```
    $connection = getConnection();
    $dbh = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO cars VALUES(?,?)");
    $dbh->bindParam(1,$idCar);
    $dbh->bindParam(2,$name);

    $dbh->execute();

    $newCarId = $dbh->lastInsertId();
    $car = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM cars WHERE id = $newCarId");

    $connection = null;

    $app->response->headers->set("Content-type","application/json");
    $app->response->status(200);
    $app->response->body(json_encode($car));
```

Note that in this case, it is safe to interpolate `$newCarId` directly into a query because it is trusted content - i.e. *not* user input.