# REST: Should we return full object or api url from a POST?

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to wrap my head around how to properly handle a POST with REST with WEB API and a C# client.

Say I have a Customer controller and I create a new customer with a POST. I think the proper thing to do after the creation of the customer in the backend is to return its REST Url in "location".

So I did this, but then, from the client I get "api/customers/17" in HttpResponseMessage.Content, if I want to get more details from that newly created customer, I need to make a GET with id 17, which means, I need to build a new url from the web api host like http://mycompany.com + the content "api/customers/17" to get info for this customer.

This does not look very elegant, so I guess I am missing something here. I know Javascript does fancy things to automatically convert this partial customer url into the actual customer object, but what if the client is a C# app. What is the recommended approach to cleanly get the created customer?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19199872/ddg#28951049

Comment: "Pretend to be a web site."

Answer (score 1):

Returning a full object from a POST isn't really necessary under normal conditions, since you probably know the object's details already.

About returning the full url: this indeed is common practice, although there is a security issue which you must consider: if a system accept full url's it's easier to let it access a non trusted resource.

So, the clean way is to return a 201, include the resource full or partial url, depending on your situation. I would stick to the full url, but, in general, all clients know the host url.